# MissingResourceException in Amazon Kindle due to Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE

Tags: android, kindle

I'm getting a java.util.MissingResourceException due to the below code in Amazon Kindle Fire, which otherwise works perfectly fine ->

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) cntx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

Any insights please if I'm missing something, which can be rectified?

Comment: Could you please post the entire stacktrace of the error please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kindle Fire is a tablet, so there isn't any available telephony service.

If you look at the documentation for [getSystemService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29) it has this:

> **Returns**
>
> The service or null if the name does not exist.